# Is this derivative correct? If yes, why?

Tags: derivatives

I need to derive the following expression with respect to $p_i$:
$$L= p_1 \cdot x_1 + \ldots + p_n \cdot x_n - \lambda \cdot x_1^{a_1} \cdot \ldots   \cdot x_n^{a_n}.$$

I found this derivation in the internet and I cannot figure out how they got this result. Is it even correct?

$$p_i-\lambda \cdot \frac {a_i}{x_i} \cdot \prod x_i^{a_i}.$$

Thank you!

EDIT: I made a mistake, it should be with respect to $x_i$!!!

Comment: Editing tip: you can group things using {} curly braces so if you want x^(a_2) you would write x^{a_2}.

Comment: Do you really mean derivative with respect to $p_i$? The answer you have written down looks more like the derivative with respect to $x_i$.

Comment: I am sorry I meant with respect to xi!! Sorry for the confusion!!

Comment: Are you familiar with $\Pi$ notation expressed in question?

Comment: Well I thought that this is operator that multiplies all the indexed $x_i^{a_i}$, right?

Comment: @Maria It's rather unfortunate notation that the answer on the internet used $i$ in the product notation too. To make it clear that they are different, I used $j$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$L= p_1 \cdot x_1 + \ldots + p_n \cdot x_n - \lambda \cdot x_1^{a_1} \cdot \ldots   \cdot x_n^{a_n}.$$

We want to find the differential of $L$ with respect to $x_i$. First we can split the derivative among the two terms:

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left ( p_1 \cdot x_1 + \ldots + p_n \cdot x_n \right ) - \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left ( \lambda \cdot x_1^{a_1} \cdot \ldots   \cdot x_n^{a_n} \right )
$$

Now consider the left portion. The only term that depends on $x_i$ is $p_i \cdot x_i$ so every term cancels in the derivative except $p_i \cdot x_i$ which differentiates to $p_i$. So:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left ( p_1 \cdot x_1 + \ldots + p_n \cdot x_n \right )  = p_i
$$

As for the second portion, this is actually pretty simple too. First notationally, notice that the second portion can be rewritten using product notation i.e.:

$$
\lambda \cdot x_1^{a_1} \cdot \ldots   \cdot x_n^{a_n} = \lambda \prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{a_j}.
$$

So we need to differentiate the right portion. Everything in this expression is a constant except $x_i^{a_i}$ when we differentiate with respect to $x_i$. So this whole thing can be seen as $Cx_i^{a_i}$ where $C$ is a constant such that

$$C = \lambda \cdot x_1^{a_1} \cdot x_2^{a_2} \ldots \cdot x_{i-1}^{a_{i-1}} \cdot x_{i+1}^{a_{i+1}} \cdot \ldots x_n^{a_n}$$

in other words $C$, is the product of everything except $x_ia_i$. This can concisely be written as :

$$
C = \frac{\lambda}{x_i^{a_i}} \prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{a_j}
$$

So we have:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left ( Cx_i^{a_i} \right )  &= C \cdot a_i x_i^{a_i - 1} \\
&= \frac{\lambda}{x_i^{a_i}} \prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{a_j} \cdot (a_i x_i^{a_i - 1})  \\
&=\frac{a_i \lambda}{x_i} \prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{a_j} 
\end{align}
$$

where we substituted in $C$ in the second step. Combining these two we get the desired result:

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_i} = p_i - \frac{a_i \lambda}{x_i} \prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{a_j} 
$$

It's rather unfortunate notation that the answer on the internet used $i$ in the product notation too. To make it clear that they are different, I used $j$ instead.

Comment: ahhh that is perfect, thank you so much!! It all makes sense now :) You made my day!

Answer (score 1):

No. The derivative should be

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial p_i} = x_i.$$

For instance, the $\lambda$-part of $L$ does not involve any $p_i$'s at all.

Edit: Answering the revised question, recall that in calculating $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_i}$, it suffices to calculate the derivative for each summand, and taking the sum of the result. Now

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} p_j x_j = \begin{cases} p_i, & i = j, \\ 0, & i \not= j, \end{cases}
$$

so that gives you your $p_i$ term. For the last term, note that

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left(- \lambda x_1^{a_1} \cdots x_n^{a_n}\right) = -\lambda x_1^{a_1} \cdots x_{i-1}^{a_{i-1}} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} x_i^{a_i} \right) x_{i+1}^{a_{i+1}} \cdots x_n^{a^n},
$$
and so the result follows from the fact that

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} x_i^{a_i} = a_i x_i^{a_i-1} = \frac{a_i}{x_i} x_i^{a_i}.
$$

Comment: Right.  The answer given by "the internet" is the derivative with respect to $x_i$.

Comment: Thank you!! I actually meant with respect to xi, I am sorry for the confusion!! Can someone explain to me step by step how to get to the derivative? I have a total black out and my calculations don't fit with this solution :(

Comment: @Maria I think the online solution is still incorrect (or perhaps you made a typo?) The second term should be $a_i \over x_i$ not $a_1 \over x_1$.

Comment: @gowrath yes, you are right it is a typo, I am sorry, it happened because I was under time pressure while writing it... It should be correct now, sorry..

Comment: Added a new answer to the question.

Comment: @fuglede Thank you so much! Finally I understand it :)